# Pull power from an exhaust fan switch for heated bidet outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I installed a new wall outlet by pulling power from an existing exhaust fan switch via the load wire. Every time the bidet is used the light starts flickering.

Would swapping the line wire with load wire help stop the flickering?

Comment: Could be a bunch of things. Model # of bidet? Picture showing the wiring to the switches, etc.?

Comment: When you say line with load are there only 2 wires at the switch a black and a white?